# How to stop GNU make buffering Python output?

Tags: python, stream, makefile

The following example Python program prints an updating progress bar.

`progress.py :`

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(100):
    sys.stdout.write("\r%3d%%" % (i + 1))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.02)
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

However, when running it through GNU Make (from Bash on Ubuntu) with the following Makefile, the output appears to be buffered until the newline character is encountered, so the progress updates are not visible. Unbuffered output is specified to Python, just to be sure.

```
all :
    python -u progress.py
```

Is there any way to get the partial-line output to be immediately visible when using make?

Comment: I just tested your example and it works perfectly for me. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and tested your example under gnome-terminal.

Comment: @user1202136, I'm on 12.04 too, and I don't see any output until the program completes. I'm using GNU Bash 4.2.24 and GNU Make 3.81. If that's all the same for you I have no idea what the difference could be.

Comment: Work fine for me too. The same versions of Bash and Make, running on Linux Mint 13 (effectively Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually tracked this down to `make` having been aliased with `colormake` in our `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

```
> type make
make is aliased to `colormake'
```

It seems `colormake` buffers output. Presumably it needs to parse a whole line before colouring it.

This was fixed by adding:

```
unalias make
```

to `~/.bashrc`.

```
> type make
make is /usr/bin/make
```